# My css is not working in bootstrap 4 how can I solve it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I am a beginner at bootstrap 4. I want to change the background of this card image. But my CSS is not working. What could be the problem here? I have tried so many ways but could not find any solution. Please help me.

Here is my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ChessStation</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

  
</head>
<body>

     <div class="container">
         <div class="row text-center py-5">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0">
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                     <div class="card shadow">
                          <div>
                               <img src="./img/p1.jpg" alt="image1" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Product1</h5>
                            <h6>
                               <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                               <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                               <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                               <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                               <i class="far fa-star-half"></i>
                            </h6>

                            <p class="card-text">
                              some quick example text to build on the card
                            </p>
                            <h5>
                              <span class="price">1000BDT</span>
                            </h5>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning my-3" name="add">Add to Cart <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </form>     
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0">
                     
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0">
                     
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0">
                     
            </div> 
         </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my style.CSS file:

```
img{
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-color: radial-gradient(white 30%, lightblue 70%) ;
  }

.fa-star,
.fa-star-half{
      color: yellow;
  }
```

Comment: It won't work. your image is .jpg so it's not transparent. you may change the background color of the image container instead.

Answer (score 4):

`background-color` will not work on `img` unless the image is `.png` or `.svg` (etc) but not `.jpg`.

I'm not really sure which `card` do you want the color to be added, but I assume it should be under `card-body`. So in your css just do:

```
.card-body {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-color: radial-gradient(white 30%, lightblue 70%) ;
  }
```

Comment: @OliUllah can you accept the answer if this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give an image a background color unless it's background is transparent.

Full Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cohen-q64pw?file=/style.css

In this code i have used a bag PNG image with transparent background and your style is now visible in the background.
Give it a try. PNG Image Link with transparent background.

https://freepngimg.com/thumb/gloves/55145-4-school-bag-free-transparent-image-hd.png

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.